# VB.NET: Error: 'Cannot be converted to Boolean' when trying to pass list/array of strings

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm trying to pass a list/array of strings to a public sub in a public module.

form 1:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String) From {"Name", "ShortNo", "test1", "test2"}
Validate(myList)
```

form 2: (Public module)

```
Public Sub Validate(ByVal Input As List(Of String))
msgbox("Hi")
End sub
```

All I want to do is pass these strings to the public module in the form of a single package i.e an array of strings or list. I've been fiddling for the last hour or two and keep getting the same error with both. I'm definitely just doing something stupid here.

I've managed to get it to not throw an error, but when I got that working it would just skip over the sub? So I have no idea. (if someone could also explain why vb.net would run past code without calling the sub, that would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it as below. It works for me. Fully qualify method call is required in order to stop the ambiguity.

```
Form2.Validate(myList)
```

Comment: My Form2 is a module; when I do the first line above I get:
"Module PublicModule cannot be used as Type"

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ok. Jeez. That's not throwing an error any more so I suppose it's working. I don't usually have to do that if the sub is in a module? Anyways, I'll start implementing what I was trying to do to see if it's fully working but I'll mark it as the answer now because it seems alright. Thanks!!